# Rename all column names that include a certain string

Tags: r, string, dplyr, data.table

Let's say I have a dataset with 6 columns, and I want to replace the strings in the names of the columns including the string "likes_comment" through the string "number_likes".

Example data:

```
da = data.frame(likes_comment_1 = c(1,2,3,4), likes_comment_2 = c(2,2,3,1), likes_comment_3=c(5,2,3,1), quotes_comment1=c(2,1,3,4), quotes_comment2_=c(3,5,7,1), quotes_comment3=c(2,3,1,2))

da
  likes_comment_1 likes_comment_2 likes_comment_3 quotes_comment1 quotes_comment2_ quotes_comment3
1               1               2               5               2                3               2
2               2               2               2               1                5               3
3               3               3               3               3                7               1
4               4               1               1               4                1               2
```

Target data:

```
target_da = data.frame(number_likes_1 = c(1,2,3,4), number_likes_2 = c(2,2,3,1), number_likes_3=c(5,2,3,1), quotes_comment1=c(2,1,3,4), quotes_comment2_=c(3,5,7,1), quotes_comment3=c(2,3,1,2))

target_da
  number_likes_1 number_likes_2 number_likes_3 quotes_comment1 quotes_comment2_ quotes_comment3
1              1              2              5               2                3               2
2              2              2              2               1                5               3
3              3              3              3               3                7               1
4              4              1              1               4                1               2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rename_with` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

da %>% rename_with(~str_replace(., 'likes_comment', 'number_likes'))

#  number_likes_1 number_likes_2 number_likes_3 quotes_comment1
#1              1              2              5               2
#2              2              2              2               1
#3              3              3              3               3
#4              4              1              1               4

#  quotes_comment2_ quotes_comment3
#1                3               2
#2                5               3
#3                7               1
#4                1               2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sub`:

```
names(da) <- sub("likes_comment_(\\d+)", "number_likes_\\1", names(da))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
names(da)[grepl('likes_comment',names(da))] <- gsub('likes_comment','number_likes',names(da)[grepl('likes_comment',names(da))])
da
  number_likes_1 number_likes_2 number_likes_3 quotes_comment1 quotes_comment2_ quotes_comment3
1              1              2              5               2                3               2
2              2              2              2               1                5               3
3              3              3              3               3                7               1
4              4              1              1               4                1               2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OP is tagged with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setnames(da, sub('likes_comment', 'number_likes', names(da), fixed = TRUE))
```